# Should servers with similar roles have one role with different profiles, or different roles per server?

Tags: puppet

I'm struggling to get my head around Puppet, and to make matters worse I'm using Red Hat Satellite 6 which adds additional layers of complexity.

I'm currently building a grpahite graphing solution. There are three types of server (relay - receives the data, cache - stores the data, graphs - runs Grafana and talks to the caches).

I have two different colleagues telling me to do it two different ways. My first available way is to create a 'role_graphing', then have 'sub-roles' such as role_graphing::relay, and so on. My second available way is to just have a role per server.

I've currently gone with the first method, and my init.pp looks like:

```
class role_graphing {   
    include profile::graphing_base
}

class role_graphing::relay inherits role_graphing {
    include profile::carbon_c_relay
}   

class role_graphing::cache inherits role_graphing {
    include profile::carbon_cache
    include profile::carbon_c_relay
    include profile::graphite_web
    include profile::memcached      
}   

class role_graphing::graph inherits role_graphing {
    include profile::graph
}
```

And then in my manifests folder, I have a profile_relay.pp, profile_cache.pp and so on. Each profile simply installs the required packages from Yum or the Forge, and then configures them.

Am I going about this the 'right' way?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of directly advising you, I will describe the intent Puppetlabs has for these terms followed by an example so you will see it generally.

Modules are collections of manifests, functions, files, templates, etc.
Profiles are collections of one or more modules.
Roles are collection of one or more profiles.
Servers are collections of one or more roles.

Example:

localhost.localdomain contains role application_server

role application_server contains profiles lamp and web_apps

profile lamp contains apache, mysql, and php modules

profile web_apps contains app_one and app_two modules

apache module contains https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache

Comment: Just a clarification that a server should belong to one role if a server needs two roles, it's better to create a new role that has the profiles of both.

Comment: @Walid That is a recommendation and not a rule. Consult the Puppet Practitioner Course for more information.

Comment: understood. I got it from Gary and PE consultants. http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/02/17/puppet-workflow-part-2/, as I understand for ENC such as foreman, sticking to one role/server recommendation makes sense as that is what these GUIs/Tools allow you. Also, if one would like to derive Enterprise service catalogue and service dependencies maps; it can be easily done and mapped. Roles represent services in service catalogue and profiles represent the higher dependency abstraction.